# Postgresql java infinite loop when connecting

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I have the following code to connect postgresql database via java but when I run this code, it always end up in infinite loop at the getConnection line. How can I handle this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:533/Airway","postgres", "abc");
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("select * from user");
        ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery();
        System.out.println(res.getString(1));
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.print(e.getMessage().toString());
        System.exit(0);
    }
    System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: `System.out.println(res.getString(1));` will throw an error because you never call `rs.next()`

Answer (score 0):

If you can't create a `Connection` it's most likely a network issue or the PostgreSQL instance is down (or listening on another port). First and foremost you want to ensure that port 533 is open and PostgreSQL is listening.

You can also specify the connection timeout in the JDBC URL [as explained in the docs, Chapter 3. Initializing the Driver](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html). This requires adding `connectTimeout` parameter (value in seconds)

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:533/Airway?connectTimeout=2
```